# Is it possible to click on a button then activate click on another button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

```js
$('.notVisible').click (function(){
  alert("im the invisivle button")
});

$('.visible').click (function(){
  alert("im the visible button")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none">
<button class="notVisible">I'm invisible</button>
</div>
<div>
<button class="visible">I'm visible</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `style` attribute and use the two classes instead. You can toggle the class of the second button when the first button is clicked. `.toggle('.visible')`

Comment: Possible, yes - look at `trigger()`. A good idea? No. Separate the functionality in to separate functions and call them where required instead of raising DOM events programmatically.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your tip! I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear what it means but "active click on a second button", if you want to "activate" the second button by bshowing it, or "activate" it by clicking it

I assume you mean the second way, in which case just add a click event to one, and inside the event, .click the other, you don't event need jQuery

`btn1.onclick = () => btn2.click()`

If you wanted to show the hidden button when one is clicked then just change the style from hidden to nothing and back, or add a class with hidden and toggle it

`btn1.onclick = () => btm2.classList.toggle("hidden")`

Then for hidden just do
`
.hidden{
display: none
}

Comment: Better to use `btn1.addEventListener('click', ...)`

Comment: @gershom why..?

Comment: Because this approach allows multiple listeners to be added for various purposes, without implementors needing to be concerned about any pre-existing listeners. If some library does `btn.onclick = () => thing1()` and I go and say `btn.onclick = () => thing2()`, clicking the button will only run my functionality, which clobbers the library's functionality. In a situation like this it's much more likely we desire to run both functions.

Answer (score 0):

Click **visible** Button -> `onclick` to hide `visible Button` and **show** `notVisible Button`

Click **notVisible** Button -> `onclick` to hide `notVisible Button` and **show** `visible Button`

```js
$('.notVisible').click (function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(".visible").show();
  alert("im the invisivle button")
});

$('.visible').click (function(){
 $(this).hide();
  $(".notVisible").show();
  alert("im the visible button")
});
```

```css
.notVisible{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="notVisible">I'm invisible</button>

<button class="visible">I'm visible</button>
```